# New ASP.NET MVC 4 Basic project does not run because of parser error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

Using **Visual Studio 2013 Update 2**, I create a new **ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application** and select the **Empty** template. I then compile and run the code and it gives the following parser error...

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error 
    Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to 
    service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details 
    and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Remote.WebPortal.MvcApplication'.

Source Error: 
    Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
              Inherits="Remote.WebPortal.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Source File:  /global.asax    Line:  1
```

So the out-of-the-box new project generation is failing for me every time. It also fails for each of the other templates as well, such as Basic, Internet Application and so forth. Restarting Visual Studio and rebooting the machine makes no difference.

The class it seems to be looing for does indeed exist, here is the **Global.asax.cs** file...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Remote.WebPortal
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I dont feel any wrong with the Global.asax file.
Please check the RouteConfig what is the default route and if any issues with that action.

Let me know if you have any controller or any actions with the default route?